Add print button to timeline notes
I have a model driven power app which includes accounts and a timeline control component with notes. I want to be able to print notes (title, description, date), however it seems that I cannot modify the note command bar in the timeline control.
How can I accomplish this behaviour using the API and JavaScript?

I tried the classic editor to find an option to modify the control, however there is only the possibility to change the form.
I also dived into the Xrm API, however I cannot find exactly what I need to extract and which functions to call to add a button.
